# How to pass function reference with parameters in kotlin? Similar to bind() in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, kotlin

Edit Start:

You can try the two code snippets below in a repl to see what I want.

Kotlin Code (doesn't work, asks for parameters in the onComplete function call)

```
fun toPass(name: String, age: Int) {
  println("Name is $name and age is $age")
}

toPass("Hakan", 26)

fun test(title: String, onComplete: (String, Int) -> Unit) {
  println("from test")
  onComplete()
  println("from test END")
}

test("customTitle", toPass("Emre", 32))
```

Javascript Code (Works)

```
function toPass(name, age) {
  console.log(`Name is ${name} and age is ${age}`)
}

toPass("Hakan", 26)

function test(title, onComplete) {
  console.log("from test")
  onComplete()
  console.log("from test END")
}

test("customTitle", toPass.bind("Emre", 32))
```

Edit End

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I want to pass a function as an onComplete callback to another function.

The reason is the callback will have locally scoped references as parameters. So I want to utilize closure here to solve my problem. Just like in javascript.

I want to bind some parameters to the function I'm passing.

```
fun functionToPass(name: String, age: Int){

}

fun someProcess(title: String, onComplete: (String, Int) -> Unit){
  var builder = AlertDialog.Builder()
  ...
  .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, object: DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
    override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
      onComplete()
    }
  })
  ...
  ...
  builder.create().show()
}
```

I want to do below, I wrote as javascript the below code, it binds the values to "name" and "age" parameters

```
someProcess("MyTitle", functionToPass.bind("Hakan", 26))
```

How can I do the same in kotlin? I only know how to send a reference, but I want to bind the values to use the closure so it's easier for me to write code logic.

Thanks

I have checked the Kotlin documentation but it shows only how to pass a reference, doesn't show an example of binding the values to parameters while passing the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really understand the problem, but I think you could do something like this:

```
fun functionToPass(name: String, age: Int) { … }

fun someProcess(title: String, onComplete: () -> Unit) {
    …
    onComplete()
    …
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
someProcess("MyTitle") { functionToPass("Hakan", 26) }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you pass a lambda function as parameter?

Also it will work the same way with a Kotlin Function

```
someProcess("My title", { "Hakan", 26 -> yourLogic })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 

Because I want to reuse this implementation, I don't want to change all the implementations of lambda functions when logic changes. And I want the implementation to work on the references I give to it.

Comment: Then pass parameters to the function, not a function and execute your callback at the end of your function, what is the purpose of "bind" parameter to a callback function instead of pass the parameters to the someProcess function?

Comment: I have two different function to call someProcess, call them a and b, a and b creates reference types locally, and I want to pass them to the function. So the "functionToPass" doesn't have access to those reference by default because of scope.